# Software Recommendation for iOS app to wake Ubuntu computer with MAC Address

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, sleep-wake

I have an Ubuntu media server set up. Currently, I can only wake it up remotely from a Terminal command on my Macbook Pro:

```
  alias wakeserver="cd ; ~/bin/wakeonlan -f ServerMACAddress.txt ; cd -;"
```

This works perfectly and starts up my server every time.

Is there an iOS app (preferably free) that will allow me to enter in the Ubuntu server's MAC Address and then wake up the server from the iOS Device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one of these apps should work:

**[iNet WOL](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/inet-wol-wake-on-lan/id318696675?mt=8)** ($1.99)

I use this app, and it works very well.

**[Mocha WOL](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/mocha-wol/id422625778?mt=8)** (free)

I haven't tried this app, but it looks like it should work just fine.